# Computation complexity of the following matrix multiplications

Tags: time-complexity, fft, matrix-multiplication

I would like to know the computational complexities of the following operations including matrices:

a) $H = \beta I + P^{T}P$ where, $\beta$ is a known constant, $I$ is a $N \times N$ identity matrix, $P$ is a $M \times N$ sparse matrix sampled from a $N \times N$ identity matrix. Thus, P contains $M$ ones and rest all elements are zeros.

b) $a =  F^{-1}Z + P^{T}B$, where $Z$ and $B$ are $N \times N$ and $M \times N$ respectively and $F{-1}$ is the inverse Fast Fourier transform (FFT).

Summary - I am not able to see how the special structure of $P$ will reduce the time complexity.

My attempt so far:
a) Since $\beta$ is a constant and we know all the places of ones in $I$, $\beta I$ will have $O(1)$ complexity.

I know multiplying two matrices of size $N \times M$ and $M \times N$ has a complexity of $O(N^{2}M) but I am not able to leverage the sparsity and special structure of P to get the actual complexity of this matrix multiplication.

b) For this one, I think that the first one will have $O(N\log N)$ complexity and the second one should have $O(N^{2}M)$ complexity, so the overall complexity will be dominated by $O(N^{2}M)$.

```py
def get_I_matrix(N):
    return np.diag(np.ones(N))
  
def get_P_matrix(picks, N):
    return get_I_matrix(N)[np.ix_(picks),:]
  
def get_H_hat_diag(N, beta, picks):
    H_hat_diag = beta*np.ones(N*N)
    P_diag = np.zeros(N)
    P_diag[picks] += 1
    H_hat_diag = H_hat_diag + np.kron(P_diag, P_diag)
    return H_hat_diag
  
def get_a_hat_vec(a_hat, z, beta):
    return (a_hat + ifftw2d(beta*z)).flatten('F') # column first

a_hat = np.zeros([N, N])
a_hat = a_hat.astype(complex)
a_hat[np.ix_(picks, picks)] = B
    
H_hat_diag = get_H_hat_diag(N, beta, picks)
a_hat_vec = get_a_hat_vec(y_hat, z, beta)
```

Since, latex isn't supported, I didn't want to write $\hat$ everywhere, hence $H$ and $a$ in the problem.

Comment: The number of multiplications and additions depends on how you implement these operations. If you give code, we can help you figure out the cost. But this way, we cannot. You can tell by this site not accepting LaTeX that this might be too theoretical a question for Stack Overflow. I would suggest to try asking in one of the sister sites, maybe the one on computer science or the one on math. If you ask “what is the most efficient way to implement these operations? this is why I’ve implemented” then it would be a fit here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I can paste the code.

Comment: For example, adding βI to a matrix is the same as adding β to the diagonal elements, so this is N operations. Likewise, multiplying by a diagonal matrix is multiplying each row by a different value, and should be implemented as such rather than a matrix multiplication. Multiplying two P by its transposed produces a diagonal matrix, should be M operations.